# How to not display any number next to outlook folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, vba

Is there any way to not display ANY number (either unread OR total) next to a folder in Outlook 2007?

I'm not opposed to a VBA solution if needed.

The options are radio buttons for some reason:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.  As you can see you can only choose one or the other.  About all you can do is complain to Microsoft.